# Return each response from a loop

Tags: javascript, axios

I have an function using axios where I am deleting multiple records based on the number of ids returned for a specific user.

```
async function DeleteAllRecords (emailAddress) {
    try {
        var accessToken = await setup.getAccessToken(emailAddress);
        var userId = await user.getUserId(emailAddress);
        var recordIds = await getAllRecordID(emailAddress);
        console.log(`Deleting all records for `+emailAddress+``);
        for (const rId of recordIds) {
            const response = await axios.delete(`${process.env.API_URL}/`+userId+`/records/`+recordIds+``, {'headers': {Authorization: 'Bearer '+accessToken+''}});
        }
        return response;
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.error(``+emailAddress+` produced the Record Delete Error = ` + e);
    }
}
```

This isn't working, and I'm unsure why. I would like to see the response for each axios.delete call, but I'm not sure how to get that. Currently its returning as response undefined.

Comment: Not related to your actual question, but you're using template strings very oddly... You can fill in values like `\`Deleting all records for ${emailAddress}!\`` instead of the in-place concatenation you have.

Comment: Not sure but isn't response block scoped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why your code didn't work:

1. `const response` is declared inside the loop scope, and is not accessible out of this closure.
2. Even if it was defined before the loop (using `let const`), and assigned inside the loop, you would still be able to return only the last response.

You can push each response to an array (`responses`), and return the array:

```
async function DeleteAllRecords (emailAddress) {
    try {
        var accessToken = await setup.getAccessToken(emailAddress);
        var userId = await user.getUserId(emailAddress);
        var recordIds = await getAllRecordID(emailAddress);
        console.log(`Deleting all records for `+emailAddress+``);
        const responses = [];
        for (const rId of recordIds) {
            const response = await axios.delete(`${process.env.API_URL}/`+userId+`/records/`+recordIds+``, {'headers': {Authorization: 'Bearer '+accessToken+''}});
            responses.push(response);
        }
        return responses;
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.error(``+emailAddress+` produced the Record Delete Error = ` + e);
    }
}
```

However, in this case multiple parallel requests would be better, since you don't actually need to delete one by one. I would use `Array.map()` to iterate the `recordIds` array, and return a promise for each one, then wait for all responses using `Promise.all()`, which would also return an array of responses:

```js
async function DeleteAllRecords (emailAddress) {
    try {
        var accessToken = await setup.getAccessToken(emailAddress);
        var userId = await user.getUserId(emailAddress);
        var recordIds = await getAllRecordID(emailAddress);
        console.log(`Deleting all records for `+emailAddress+``);
        
        return Promise.all(recordIds.map(rId =>  axios.delete(`${process.env.API_URL}/`+userId+`/records/`+recordIds+``, {'headers': {Authorization: 'Bearer '+accessToken+''}})));
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.error(``+emailAddress+` produced the Record Delete Error = ` + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This isn't working, and I'm unsure why. I would like to see the response for each axios.delete call, but I'm not sure how to get that. Currently its returning as response undefined.

There are several issues in your code:

- `const response` declared within loop block, but you try to return it after the loop. `const` and `let` are strictly block scoped, thus by referring to `response` after the loop block basically tells JS to return an undefined variable.
- You write several times to `response`. If the issue above wasnt in place, it would still not work correctly, since you only would end up with the response of the last loop run. Here you'd have to collect the response from all runs, e.g. into a list.